# Engelmacher means someone who helps with abortions?

Tags: german-to-english, pronoun, slang, proper-noun

Does the German word of "Angelmaker" mean someone who helps with abortions? How did that come about historically.

If so, how would this word classify, specifically. Double entendre, idiom, or slang word?

Comment: Did you look into Wikipedia? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engelmacher

Comment: What did you find in dictionaries?

Comment: Never knew about it in English-speaking countries

Comment: The French Wikipedia entry says a definition was proposed by Émile Littré, en 1877, giving the impression that she has *coined* the term "Faiseuse d'Anges". I find it difficult to confirm that had she had not simply addopted a preexisting idiom from argot. Since *ing* would be a regular reflex of PIE \*neḱ- "to disappear, perrish", and there is no biblical precedent of the dead becoming angels (that's an apocryphal narrative as far as I know) I think this topic is very dubious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## **It's a euphemism**

Some people believe, that when you die you go to heaven and become an angel.

Originally *Engelmacherin* was used to describe women, who took children in their care (e.g. orphans) but did not or could not feed them sufficiently, so the children subsequently starved to death (=became angels, prematurely). This expression then was expanded (in slang) to denote people that conducted abortions.

Source: [wiktionary and sources therein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Engelmacherin)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know the first meaning. That's terrible.

Comment: Are there other similar German euphemisms with a biblical bent?

Comment: @user610620: there's the related *himmeln*, see https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/himmeln no. 2 and 3. I've heard of himmeln as Euphemism for infanticide (I have no source, but it's basically the combination of those 2 meanings), along the lines: "Das Kind wurde gehimmelt" (possibly by the Engelmacherin of this answer).

Answer (score 4):

I meet this terminology on 3 languages, incl. German, and it has meant abortionists or infanticide on all of them. The terminology was more common in the Europe of the first half of the previous century, where abortion was banned and contraceptives did not exist yet. It was an euphemism even at the time.

It is because if children die, they die without committing sins. Sins can be committed only intentionally in the Christianity, and children can not (yet) do that. Thus, they go into the Heaven. All of them. If they will become angels, probably no one knows it on Earth for sure.

However, killing children, for this purpose, or for any other purpose, is a deadly sin itself and *not* an acceptable way to send someone into the Heaven. The only acceptable way to that if you help them to grow up, and to live a life with few sins, acceptable for the divine grace. Killing children is an unimaginable crime, and "Engelmacher/in" is an euphemism for children murderers, included the abortionists.

Comment: Could you specify the languages where you encountered this? And: Is the idea that sins can be committed only intentionally limited to a certain historic and confessional context? If so, it would make sense to add this piece of information. I think, "killing children [...] purpose, is a deadly sin itself " might be a little unclear. I think you want to explain how "Engelmacherin" was a euphemism and express that this was a position of Christianity at that time. The way you wrote it, it could be interpreted as stating your personal opinion. That could spark a debate, and this is not the place.

Comment: Yes I do it after *Kernarbeitszeit*

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach The [German Wikipedia page for Engelmacher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engelmacher) links to a [French page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faiseuse_d%27anges) which seems to confirm that the equivalent term exists there. There are also [Swedish](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84nglamakerska) and [Norwegian](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Englemakeri) pages for similar terms, but they are only used in the original meaning described by infinitezero, referring to women taking care of orphan's (and possibly mistreating them to the point of death).

Comment: Never came across this term's usage in English-speaking countries though

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach [English](http://www.hhogman.se/angel_maker.htm), [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engelmacher), [Hungarian](https://hu.wiktionary.org/wiki/angyalcsin%C3%A1l%C3%B3). It is mirror translation on all of them. On the last, the terminology is very likely German import from the era of the Monarchie. Note, the current political era promotes lenience toward abortions and this affects the available public content. I am thinking on, how to inject this into the post.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Sins are inherently intentional in the Christianity. It is because your life is a chain of decisions, where do you want to go after your death. Sins are the choices where you elect the hell. As far I know, all major denominations agree that, particularly in the Germany most common Lutheranism, whose ideas in this sense are practically the same to the Roman Catholicism. Protestants differ a lot, because they (mostly) deny free will, but probably not so much. And Germany is mainly Evangelist, a lesser extent Catholic.

Comment: This is not the place for theological discussions. It would also be nice if ideology could be left out of answers or at least be marked as such.

Comment: @CarstenS I could reformulate the answer to a neutral point of view, and I wish to do so. However, I am not sure that it will be enough. Problem is that history, Christianity and the social situation of the previous centuries are essential part of the etimology of the word.

Comment: Kondome sind auch Kontrazeptiva und älter als 120 Jahre.

Comment: Dem christlichen Glauben nach hat der Mensch seit Adam & Eva eine Erbsünde, weswegen es keine Menschen ohne Sünde gibt, auch keine Kinder. Ungetaufte Kinder haben deswegen keine Chance in den Himmel zu kommen - das begründet erst, dass Abtreibung selbst eine Sünde ist: Man enthält Gott mögliche Heerscharen im Himmel vor. Von religiösen Fundamentalisten abgesehen hält auch niemand Föten für Kinder. Ein Kind ist ein geborener Mensch, der außerhalb des Mutterleibes lebensfähig ist.